# How to filter only the longest line after Hough Transform

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, lines, hough-transform

I'm currently using the Hough Transform to get the straight lines. But there are a lot of lines detected. Can I know how to filter and only get the longest line from the output?

```
      HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 20, 10 ); //left lane

      for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
      {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        double theta1,theta2, hyp, result;

        theta1 = (l[3]-l[1]);
        theta2 = (l[2]-l[0]);
        hyp = hypot(theta1,theta2);

        line( cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(255,0,0), 3, CV_AA);

        }

      imshow("detected lines", cdst);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're literally a step away:

The `hypot` function gives you the distance between the start and end points. Now, simply find the longest such distance, and the corresponding line is the longest.

```
Vec4i max_l;
double max_dist = -1.0;

for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    double theta1,theta2, hyp, result;

    theta1 = (l[3]-l[1]);
    theta2 = (l[2]-l[0]);
    hyp = hypot(theta1,theta2);

    if (max_dist < hyp) {
        max_l = l;
        max_dist = hyp;
    }           
}

// max_l now has the line of maximum length
line( cdst, Point(max_l[0], max_l[1]), Point(max_l[2], max_l[3]), Scalar(255,0,0), 3, CV_AA);
// do something else with max_l
```

Comment: "// l now has your line of maximum length"  No. l is the last element of lines. You don't update max_dist, so max_dist < hyp is valid for all lines...

Comment: @FooBar : Ooopsies. Terribly sorry. My bad. Updated now, thanks!

Comment: Hi @aspiring_sarge and FooBar, I tried but seems like the all the lines are still appearing. Is it due to the for loop? Or do I need to put it somewhere first? Still debugging

Comment: Of course all lines are appearing. If you only want to draw the longest line, you have to move the line(...) out of the loop.

Comment: @MazAhmad : Sorry. I did not realize that you wanted to display the longest line, but merely thought you wanted to do something with it. Answer updated.

Comment: @FooBar too!! you guys surely know to read the codes faster.. thanks!!

Comment: Out of blue ... would the query of finding the shortest lines can be altered from the code above?

Comment: Yes. Simply replace `double max_dist = -1.0;` with a very large value, and the statement `if (max_dist < hyp)` with `if (max_dist > hyp)`. Actually, it might be better to simply replace the statement `if (max_dist < hyp)` with `if (max_dist > hyp || max_dist == -1.0)`. A third way of this doing (which, IMO, is the neatest) would be to store the very first line length in `max_dist`, and the first line itself in `max_l`, before the start of the loop. Note that it might be better to change all variables that start with `max_` to start with `min_`, to avoid confusion later on ;)

Comment: Out of blue ... would the query of finding the shortest lines can be altered from the code above? and why do we need to declare this double max_dist = -1.0;? try to calculate the logic from the eucledian process and pyhtogoras theorem.