# Longest line detection using Hough Line Transform

Tags: c#, image-processing, hough-transform

I want to **[detect longest line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29818831/159072)** in an image using Hough Transform.

Input image

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Present output

[image]

We can see that it detected the incorrect line.

**Where, in the following code, should I look for the bug?**

There is one catch though. The source code appears to produce correct output if I increase the threshold value from 50 to 150. But, to me, this doesn't make any sense as increased threshold means excluding lowly voted lines.

.

**Source Code**

*HoughLineTransform.cs*

```
public class Line
{
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }
    public int Length 
    {
        get 
        {
            return (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(End.X - Start.X, 2) + Math.Pow(End.Y - Start.Y, 2)); ;
        }
    }
    public Line()
    {

    }
    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }
}

public class HoughLineTransform
{
    public HoughMap Accumulator { get; set; }

    public HoughLineTransform() {}

    public Line GetLongestLine()
    {
        List<Line> lines = GetLines(50);

        int maxIndex = 0;
        double maxLength = -1.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (maxLength < lines[i].Length)
            {
                maxIndex = i;
                maxLength = lines[i].Length;
            }
        }

        return lines[maxIndex];
    }

    public List<Line> GetLines(int threshold)
    {
        if (Accumulator == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("HoughMap is null");
        }

        int houghWidth = Accumulator.Width;
        int houghHeight = Accumulator.Height;
        int imageWidth = Accumulator.Image.GetLength(0);
        int imageHeight = Accumulator.Image.GetLength(1);

        List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

        if (Accumulator == null)
            return lines;

        for (int rho = 0; rho < houghWidth; rho++)
        {
            for (int theta = 0; theta < houghHeight; theta++)
            {
                if ((int)Accumulator[rho, theta] > threshold)
                {
                    //Is this point a local maxima (9x9)
                    int peak = Accumulator[rho, theta];

                    for (int ly = -4; ly <= 4; ly++)
                    {
                        for (int lx = -4; lx <= 4; lx++)
                        {
                            if ((ly + rho >= 0 && ly + rho < houghWidth) && (lx + theta >= 0 && lx + theta < houghHeight))
                            {
                                if ((int)Accumulator[rho + ly, theta + lx] > peak)
                                {
                                    peak = Accumulator[rho + ly, theta + lx];
                                    ly = lx = 5;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (peak > (int)Accumulator[rho, theta])
                        continue;

                    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
                    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0;

                    double rad = theta * Math.PI / 180;

                    if (theta >= 45 && theta <= 135)
                    {
                        //y = (r - x Math.Cos(t)) / Math.Sin(t)
                        x1 = 0;
                        y1 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((x1 - (imageWidth / 2)) * Math.Cos(rad))) / Math.Sin(rad) + (imageHeight / 2));
                        x2 = imageWidth - 0;
                        y2 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((x2 - (imageWidth / 2)) * Math.Cos(rad))) / Math.Sin(rad) + (imageHeight / 2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //x = (r - y Math.Sin(t)) / Math.Cos(t);
                        y1 = 0;
                        x1 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((y1 - (imageHeight / 2)) * Math.Sin(rad))) / Math.Cos(rad) + (imageWidth / 2));
                        y2 = imageHeight - 0;
                        x2 = (int)(((double)(rho - (houghWidth / 2)) - ((y2 - (imageHeight / 2)) * Math.Sin(rad))) / Math.Cos(rad) + (imageWidth / 2));
                    }

                    lines.Add(new Line(new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2)));
                }
            }
        }

        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m too lazy to read all that code. Are you taking the number of pixels as the line length (I.e. the value of the bin in the accumulator)? Number of pixels is a poor substitute for line length. But since you know the angle too, you can compensate and get a pretty accurate estimate of line length from that count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm is actually easy to understand even at the first glance it seems the opposite. 
It is based on the following *line* formula:

```
ρ = cos(θ) * x + sin(θ) * y
```

where  *ρ*  is the perpendicular distance from the origin to the line, and *θ* is the angle formed by this perpendicular line and horizontal axis.

[image]

If you know ρ and θ you know the line. If you take all possible pairs (within a given accuracy) 
of *ρ* and *θ* you actually get all possible lines that can exist in your image. That is what
`Map[ρ, θ ]` stores. If you want the accuracy of angles to be 1 degree, you need 180 columns. For ρ, the maximum distance possible is the diagonal length of the image. So taking one pixel accuracy, the number of rows can be the diagonal length of the image. But **not** your 
image, a square one (in *HoughMap.cs*):

```
int maxTheta = 180;
int houghHeight = (int)( Math.Sqrt( 2 ) * Math.Max( imgWidth, imgHeight ) ) / 2;
int doubleHoughHeight = houghHeight * 2;
```

`doubleHoughHeight` is the diagonal of the square, that’s why it takes `Math.Max`!

Every point of your image is being mapped on your *Map* array:

```
     ρ                      θ    number of points in that line( pair (ρ, θ) )
Map  0                      0    num0
     0                      1    num1
     0                      2    num2
     .                      .    .
     .                      .    .
     doubleHoughHeight – 1  179  numN
```

*threshold* filters out the lines with less than 50 points. Also the following code filters out lines:

```
//Is this point a local maxima (9x9)
int peak = Accumulator[ rho, theta ];

for( int ly = -4; ly <= 4; ly++ ) {
    for( int lx = -4; lx <= 4; lx++ ) {
        if( ( ly + rho >= 0 && ly + rho < houghWidth ) && ( lx + theta >= 0 && lx + theta < houghHeight ) ) {
            if( (int)Accumulator[ rho + ly, theta + lx ] > peak ) {
                peak = Accumulator[ rho + ly, theta + lx ];
                    ly = lx = 5;
             }
         }
     }
 }

 if( peak > (int)Accumulator[ rho, theta ] )
     continue;
```

The actual issue you have can be seen in the following images:

[image]

[image]

The *End* and *Start* points you get are actually the intersection points of the lines and both axis:

```
int x1, y1, x2, y2;
x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0;

double rad = theta * Math.PI / 180;

if( theta >= 45 && theta <= 135 ) {
    //y = (r - x Math.Cos(t)) / Math.Sin(t)
    x1 = 0;
    y1 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( x1 - ( imageWidth / 2 ) ) * Math.Cos( rad ) ) ) / Math.Sin( rad ) + ( imageHeight / 2 ) );
    x2 = imageWidth - 0;
    y2 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( x2 - ( imageWidth / 2 ) ) * Math.Cos( rad ) ) ) / Math.Sin( rad ) + ( imageHeight / 2 ) );
}
else {
    //x = (r - y Math.Sin(t)) / Math.Cos(t);
    y1 = 0;
    x1 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( y1 - ( imageHeight / 2 ) ) * Math.Sin( rad ) ) ) / Math.Cos( rad ) + ( imageWidth / 2 ) );
    y2 = imageHeight - 0;
    x2 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( y2 - ( imageHeight / 2 ) ) * Math.Sin( rad ) ) ) / Math.Cos( rad ) + ( imageWidth / 2 ) );
}

lines.Add( new Line( new Point( x1, y1 ), new Point( x2, y2 ) ) );
```

**EDIT**

Your code works fine but it doesn't calculate the actual length. A solution I found is to store all the points for every position of the 2D *Map* array. In
your *HoughMap.cs*:

```
public List<Point>[] lstPnts { get; set; }

public void Compute() {
    if( Image != null ) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        Map = new int[ doubleHoughHeight, maxTheta ];

        //Add this code////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //lstPnts is an doubleHoughHeight * maxTheta size array of list Points
        lstPnts = new List<Point>[ doubleHoughHeight * maxTheta ];

        for(int i = 0; i < doubleHoughHeight * maxTheta; i++ ) {
            lstPnts[ i ] = new List<Point>();
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ....
        ....
        ....
        if( ( rho > 0 ) && ( rho <= Map.GetLength( 0 ) ) ) {
            Map[ rho, theta ]++;
            //Add this line of code////////////////////////////////////////
            lstPnts[ rho * maxTheta + theta ].Add( new Point( x, y ) );
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            PointsCount++;
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

In *HoughLineTransform.cs*

```
public List<Line> GetLines( int threshold ) {
    if( Accumulator == null ) {
        throw new Exception( "HoughMap is null" );
    }

    int houghWidth = Accumulator.Width;
    int houghHeight = Accumulator.Height;
    int imageWidth = Accumulator.Image.GetLength( 0 );
    int imageHeight = Accumulator.Image.GetLength( 1 );

    List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

    if( Accumulator == null )
        return lines;

    for( int rho = 0; rho < houghWidth; rho++ ) {
        for( int theta = 0; theta < houghHeight; theta++ ) {
            if( (int)Accumulator[ rho, theta ] > threshold ) {
                //Is this point a local maxima (9x9)
                int peak = Accumulator[ rho, theta ];
                int dd = 10;

                for( int ly = -dd; ly <= dd; ly++ ) {
                    for( int lx = -dd; lx <= dd; lx++ ) {
                        if( ( ly + rho >= 0 && ly + rho < houghWidth ) && ( lx + theta >= 0 && lx + theta < houghHeight ) ) {
                            if( (int)Accumulator[ rho + ly, theta + lx ] > peak ) {
                                peak = Accumulator[ rho + ly, theta + lx ];
                                ly = lx = dd + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if( peak > (int)Accumulator[ rho, theta ] )
                    continue;

                //Map[ rho, theta ] contains these points -> lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ].
                //The points in that list with min and max X coordinate are the Start and End ones
                int x1 = houghWidth, y1 = 0, x2 = -1, y2 = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < Accumulator.lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ].Count; i++ ) {
                    if( Accumulator.lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ][ i ].X > x2 ) {
                        x2 = Accumulator.lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ][ i ].X;
                        y2 = Accumulator.lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ][ i ].Y;
                    }

                    if( Accumulator.lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ][ i ].X < x1 ) {
                        x1 = Accumulator.lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ][ i ].X;
                        y1 = Accumulator.lstPnts[ rho * houghHeight + theta ][ i ].Y;
                    }
                }


                //Remove this code
                /*int x1, y1, x2, y2;
                x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0;

                double rad = theta * Math.PI / 180;

                if( theta >= 45 && theta <= 135 ) {
                    //y = (r - x Math.Cos(t)) / Math.Sin(t)
                    x1 = 0;
                    y1 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( x1 - ( imageWidth / 2 ) ) * Math.Cos( rad ) ) ) / Math.Sin( rad ) + ( imageHeight / 2 ) );
                    x2 = imageWidth - 0;
                    y2 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( x2 - ( imageWidth / 2 ) ) * Math.Cos( rad ) ) ) / Math.Sin( rad ) + ( imageHeight / 2 ) );
                }
                else {
                    //x = (r - y Math.Sin(t)) / Math.Cos(t);
                    y1 = 0;
                    x1 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( y1 - ( imageHeight / 2 ) ) * Math.Sin( rad ) ) ) / Math.Cos( rad ) + ( imageWidth / 2 ) );
                    y2 = imageHeight - 0;
                    x2 = (int)( ( (double)( rho - ( houghWidth / 2 ) ) - ( ( y2 - ( imageHeight / 2 ) ) * Math.Sin( rad ) ) ) / Math.Cos( rad ) + ( imageWidth / 2 ) );
                }*/

                lines.Add( new Line( new Point( x1, y1 ), new Point( x2, y2 ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

    return lines;
}
```